# Wayland Nvidia fps is half of the refresh rate of the external monitor

Tags: kde, nvidia, wayland, nixos

I'm running NixOS 23.05 with KDE on my lenovo legion 5 laptop that has an external monitor attached via HDMI.

When using wayland the fps I get is always half of the selected refresh rate (for refresh rates above 60). When 144 Hz is selected I get round 72 fps, and when 120 Hz is selected I get around 60, but strangely, when 60 Hz is selected I do get 60 fps. Applications on the internal monitor run with the correct refresh/framerate (currently set to 165 Hz/fps).

I'm using the proprietary nvidia drivers (version 470.182.03 at the moment), I also tried 530, but it had a different issue. On nouveau the framerate matches the refresh rate, but I get visual glitches when fractional scaling is enabled. On X11 I have trouble with the multi-monitor setup.

How do I fix the refresh-rate issue? I cannot switch to X11, and I cannot use nouveau for the issues mentioned above.

Relevant contents of configuration.nix:

```
 # Graphics
  # Make sure opengl is enabled
  hardware.opengl = {
    enable = true;
    driSupport = true;
    driSupport32Bit = true;
  };
  # Tell Xorg to use the nvidia driver (also valid for Wayland)
  services.xserver.videoDrivers = ["nvidia"];
  hardware.nvidia = {
        # Modesetting is needed for most Wayland compositors
        modesetting.enable = true;

        # Use the open source version of the kernel module
        # Only available on driver 515.43.04+
        open = false;
  
        # Enable the nvidia settings menu
        nvidiaSettings = false;
  
        # Optionally, you may need to select the appropriate driver version for your specific GPU.
        package = config.boot.kernelPackages.nvidiaPackages.legacy_470;
    };
    hardware.nvidia.prime = {
        offload = {
          enable = true;
          enableOffloadCmd = true;
        };
    
        amdgpuBusId = "PCI:6:0:0";
        nvidiaBusId = "PCI:1:0:0";
      };
```